# Linux Distro name API to get name of linux distro in a driver code?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, drivers, kernel-modules

I am writing a common code in a driver to get the distros name and host name. host name i am taking from `struct utsname{nodename[]}`, but how do I get the distro name?

Comment: It really doesn't make sense to talk about distro inside the kernel. In userland you can call `lsb_release -i` though.

Comment: Need to add a sysfs entry for my driver. That is why I am trying to get it inside kernel. @o11c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Scope for getting distro name is not in kernel development scope. So no specific method is present currently. I am asking for module param in my driver for this. you can also ask for a ENV variable while compiling.

Thanks, for your help...

Answer (score 1):

Most programs and scripts I've seen parse the usual files in `/etc`, AFAIK there's no other way:

```
On Redhat, look for /etc/redhat-release
On Debian, look for /etc/debian_version
Mandriva has /etc/version
and Slackware has /etc/slackware-version
```

You could also use `uname` to get the `ARCH` or, probably the most sane way, use `lsb_release`.

Comment: thanks for your response. I need this info. in kernel space. It would be helpful if some can help me to get distro name in kernel space.

Comment: What you're looking for **does not exist**.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at how facter does it [here](https://github.com/puppetlabs/facter/blob/master/lib/facter/operatingsystem/linux.rb).

As Jan said, lsb_release is probably the best way to go, but it cannot be your only way. For example, lsb_release is not present by default on any of my RHEL servers:

```
[damaya@damaya-sandbox script]$ lsb_release
-bash: lsb_release: command not found
[damaya@damaya-sandbox script]$ yum provides "*/lsb_release"
redhat-lsb-core-4.0-7.el6.centos.i686 : LSB base libraries support for CentOS
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/lsb_release
```

So, if lsb_release is not present on the system, then your next step is to get the information from the /etc/*-release file. However, if that is also not present on the system then you are out of luck. Unfortunately, there does not exist a 100% reliable way to get this information.